# How to declare a matrix with two columns and unknown number of rows in C

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

I need to create a matrix with 2 columns and unknown number of rows. I know I have to use malloc but I can't find how to declare such matrix. it should hold integers in the first column and doubles in the second. How do I do that?

Comment: To get a helpful answer, you first need to tell us what you tried and where you got stuck, so we can be sure you tried to solve this talk for yourself. This site is not a homework service.

Comment: "it should hold integers in the first column and doubles in the second" -- then it's not a "matrix".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct item {

  int i;
  double d;
};

struct item matrix = malloc(sizeof(struct item) * number_of_rows)

matrix[0].i = 544343;
matrix[0].d = 0.3434343;
```

Is that the code you are looking for?

Comment: And please use more meaningful names!

Comment: something like that yes but isn't it supposed to be something like                                     
                                                                                                                                   //int num = something;                                                                                         
 double *matrix=malloc(sizeof(double)*num);                                                               matrix[][2]={{0}};

Comment: @spaceNugget in C arrays (a matrix is a 2d array) can contain only homogeneous data. That's why Ed showed to you the implementation of an array of records (struct) each made up of an integer and a double.

Comment: @Robert addressed what I was referring to.  Comment deleted.

Comment: You could argue it is a matrix of two columns. One being an int and the other a double

Comment: You could - But you probably wouldn't want to.  At least if meanings of words are important to you. :)  ( [eg.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm) )

Comment: @ryyker - An array is a matrix that just has one column?

Comment: A matrix is a mathematical concept and not C. You could say that `struct item` which consists of `[i, d]` is a row by treating and transforming it like a one (_ie_ linearly.)

Comment: Note that struct may have padding bytes due to satisfaction on alignment constraints. The size of struct may be 16 while only 12 bytes (4 int and 8 double) are relevant. As result 25% of memory is wasted